# Is it possible to load a runtime shared library into JavaScript and use it

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to load a runtime shared library into JavaScript and use it? Are there any security concerns about allowing to load an .so file?

Comment: How will Javascript use an .so?  I don't think it's possible; I think the security concerns would be grave.

Comment: If you're talking about running JavaScript within a web page there would definitely be security concerns, why would you do that?

Comment: @duffymo in the similar way C++, C#, Java, ObjectiveC, Phython, TCL, Perl and many other languages do that

Comment: What environment are we talking about here?  Modern-day web browsers, node.js, spidermonkey, Nashorn, one of the more popular .NET JavaScript run times, something else?

Comment: None of those other languages run in a web browser with that same purpose as Javascript.  It's not like other languages, nor should it be.

Comment: @duffymo you are completely correct, that these languages run in different way. But being different does not explain why it cannot be done. More details are necessary.

Comment: Can't be done because it completely breaks the Javascript sandbox model, if I understand it correctly.  That's enough for me.  Have to do it on the server side with Java and JNI.

Answer (score 0):

In a web browser? I think it's impossible.

Server-side programming (like Node.js) maybe possible. not sure of that.

Well in java can do sth like this

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
String js = "var t=" + someJNIMethod()+";"
engine.eval(js);
```

It's not practical, but possible.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js with [FFI](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) module will help on this case